# ASP.NET Log Out Event Handler and Site.Master Page

Tags: asp.net, forms, web

I am using a Site.Master file to create a log in/log out field on every page using the following code:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" >
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" OnLoggedOut="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

However, when the user logs out, I want to be able to run the event handler

```
OnLoggedOut="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut"
```

And edit some information in a user table (e.g. last log out time and what not). However, I don't know how to retrieve this information since

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
```

apparently does not work in Site.Master.cs (User does not exist in context). Is there some other way to retrieve user info? Also, is there a way to transfer information (e.g. using querystring) from the page the user clicked "log out"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this are you looking for?

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

Or if you need only the UserName...

```
String id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```